# How to run several shell scripts but terminate all of them if one encounters an error / does not terminate successfully?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a shell script that runs several other shell scripts in parallel e.g. `./run_all.sh` contains

```
./run1.sh &
./run2.sh &
./run3.sh &

wait
echo "All 3 complete"
```

How can I terminate all processes if one of them exits due to an error etc? The `&&` requires each script to terminate successfully but it runs sequentially.

Comment: Did you try the `wait -n` command? See: https://linuxize.com/post/bash-wait/

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this:

```
  { run1.sh || killtheothers.sh 1 ; } &
  { run2.sh || killtheothers.sh 2 ; } &
  { run3.sh || killtheothers.sh 3 ; } &
```

so that each command is run in the background (via the `&`) but if any command fails (returns an error, i.e. non-zero, status) then the "or" control operator `||` allows the "killtheothers.sh" script to run.
You'll have to write killtheothers.sh, perhaps using the "killall" command.  I showed it using a parameter to specify which runX command the script wouldn't need to kill.